# Не срабатывает миграция конфига webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack4

Решил обновит зависимости в package.json. 3 вебпак,который я использовался трансформировался в 4-й, который потребовал webpack-cli и наложил свои ограничения. В документации по cli есть портирование старого конфига в новый командой `webpack-cli migrate <config>` насколькоя  понял больше ничгео никуда писать не надо. Я перехожу в папку со своим конфигом вебпака и выполняю `webpack-cli migrate webpack.config.js`. В ответ он пишет: `webpack-cli: command not found` В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта:
1 - установить `webpack-cli` глобально: `npm install -g webpack-cli`
2 - запускать `webpack-cli` из `node_modules`, поищите по такому пути ( возможно там по другому файл называется, `ls` в помощь ):

```
node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack_cli.js
```